# error passing data using controller (laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I was passing data on a variable using my controller:

```
public function editpage($cart_id){

        $carts = DB::table('carts')
        ->join('shoes', 'carts.shoe_id','=','shoes.id')
        ->select('shoes.shoe_name','shoes.shoe_image','carts.quantity','shoes.shoe_price')
        ->where('carts.id',$cart_id)
        ->get(); 

        return view('editcart',compact('carts'));
    }
```

And here is my blade:

```html
    @extends('layouts.app')
    
    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">EditCart</div>
                     <img src="{{ asset("$carts->shoe_image") }}" alt="" style="width:200px; height:200px;"> 
                    {{$carts->shoe_name}}
                    {{$carts->quantity}}
                    ${{$carts->shoe_price * $carts->quantity}} 
    
                    {{dd($carts)}}
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

it says, that `$carts` doesn't have attribute `shoe_image`

Here is my `dd($carts)`:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1216 ▼
  #items: array:1 [▼
    0 => {#1226 ▼
      +"shoe_name": "Boot Double G"
      +"shoe_image": "4.jpg"
      +"quantity": 12
      +"shoe_price": 500
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to call the `$carts->shoe_image`, etc. on my blade. It says that it has the value when I `dd($carts)` but when i want to use it, it says that it doesn't have the value.

Comment: What is exactly error image is not displaying ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the contents of your blade view file, it seems that you are trying to display a form to edit the cart.

In that case you must return a single cart record from the controller, user firstOrFail() instead of get()

```php
public function editpage($cart_id){

    $carts = DB::table('carts')
        ->join('shoes', 'carts.shoe_id','=','shoes.id')
        ->select('shoes.shoe_name','shoes.shoe_image','carts.quantity','shoes.shoe_price')
        ->where('carts.id',$cart_id)
        ->firstOrFail(); 

    return view('editcart',compact('carts'));
}
```